# Setting IIS6 File Redirection Programmatically

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, iis-6

In IIS6 you can go into IIS Manager and set the properties of a file to be a permanent redirection, and there's also other tabs to set the security, headers, etc. See below for a screenshot.

[IIS Manager File Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rcF5.png)

Is there a similar way to do this, but from the command line where I could do this for a thousand files at once?

For background: We are migrating content off this legacy system, but several external systems link directly to it. Those links will expire after a period of time, but updating those external systems will be a larger task than just setting redirects file by file to the new system (even by hand if needed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer immediately after posting (which seems to happen all too often).

> In IIS, you can configure redirects on file level. From within IIS Manager, this is done by right clicking the file, click Properties and then select "A redirection to a URL". This is however impractical if you need to do this on many files, so it can of course be done from a command line or by code. Using adsutil.vbs you can use the following command lines to set a redirection on an individual file:

```
CSCRIPT %SYSTEMDRIVE%\Inetpub\AdminScripts\adsutil.vbs CREATE W3SVC/1/ROOT/vdir/oldFile.htm IIsWebFile 
CSCRIPT %SYSTEMDRIVE%\Inetpub\AdminScripts\adsutil.vbs SET W3SVC/1/ROOT/vdir/oldFile.htm/HttpRedirect "http://www.gafvert.info"
```

> In the example above, 1 is the website ID, vdir a virtual directory and oldFile.htm the file in the virtual directory.

*Amending my answer now that I've tested it*

On my Server 2003/IIS 6 box I could not use those exact commands, but instead had to execute like this to create the virtual file and then assign the KeyType/Properties.

```
SET FILE=/W3SVC/1/ROOT/test/redirection/File Path.pdf
CSCRIPT %SYSTEMDRIVE%\Inetpub\AdminScripts\adsutil.vbs CREATE "%FILE%"
CSCRIPT %SYSTEMDRIVE%\Inetpub\AdminScripts\adsutil.vbs SET "%FILE%/KeyType" "IIsWebFile"
CSCRIPT %SYSTEMDRIVE%\Inetpub\AdminScripts\adsutil.vbs SET "%FILE%/HttpRedirect" "http://www.google.com, EXACT_DESTINATION, PERMANENT"
```

You can also set content expiration, custom headers, etc. from this interface.

[Source](http://www.it-notebook.org/iis/article/questions_0737.htm)